# How to prove expected value of uniform random variable?

Tags: calculus, statistics

I tried this:

$$\int_a^b t~dt = \frac{t^2}{2}\Big]_a^b = \frac{b^2-a^2}{2} = \frac{(b+a)(b-a)}{2}$$

Isn't it supposed to be $\frac{b+a}{2}$ or something like that? Obviously if I multiply the integral by $\frac{1}{b-a}$ I get the intended result but I don't understand what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ has support $[a,b]$ with density $f(t)$, then $E(T)=\int_a^b tf(t)dt$. In your case, you have forgotten $f(t)=\frac{1}{b-a}$.

---

For a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ with $a<b$, uniformity means that the density $f(t)$ is some constant $c$ for $t\in[a,b]$. The density is required to integrate to $1$ and so $1=\int_a^bf(t)dt=\int_a^b cdt=c\int_a^b dt=c(b-a)$ which gives $c=\frac{1}{b-a}$.

Comment: How is density defined here? Why do I have a fraction multiplied by an integral? What does each piece represent?

Comment: @DoubleBass I have added a bit. Is it clearer now? You should have seen what a probability density is by now if you are integrating a continuous random variable to obtain its expected value.

Comment: So does the "density" just tell me the probability at a particular point in the interval?

Comment: The probability at a particular point is zero -- think of it in terms of density of a material versus a point mass in physics. Maybe you should read your text for what a probability density function is.

Answer (score 1):

A uniform random variable $X$ on $[a,b]$ has density $\frac{1}{b-a} on that interval.

So, $E[X] = \int_{a}^b x \frac{1}{b-a} dx = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b x dx = \frac{1}{b-a} \frac{b^2-a^2}{2} = \frac{b+a}{2}$.

Comment: How is density defined here? Why do I have a fraction multiplied by an integral? What does each piece represent?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a uniform distribution on the interval $[a,b]$ you need to have a probability density function associated with your sampling process.  The density function $f(t)$ on $[a,b]$ is a constant since any piece of the interval is equally likely to be sampled, but the question is what constant is it?  Suppose $f(t) = c$.  Then We should be able to integrate $f(t)$ and obtain $1$ (corresponding to unit probability), thus

$$
\int_a^b f(t) dt \;\; =\;\; c \int_a^b dt \;\; =\;\; c(b-a) \;\; =\;\; 1
$$

hence $c = \frac{1}{b-a}$.  Thus when you compute the expectation value, you want to integrate $\int_a^b tf(t)dt$ and this will give you your desired result.